# Jquery ajax get string after success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a textarea and needed value is multiple string separated with newline. After success, only the last stringf is caught. Here is my code:

```
var stringf;
    var lines = $('#bulk_string').val().split('\n');
        for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){    
            if(lines[i].length > 0){
                stringf = lines[i];
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajaxuser.php",
                data: 'do=submit&info='+stringf, 
            success: function(data) 
            {
                $('#string_list').append('<li>'+stringf+' '+data</li>');
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop will finish looping pretty much instantly, but your AJAX call will take a while to process and return back to you. Because of this, by the time your AJAX call has completed the `stringf` value will be set to whatever was assigned to it in the final iteration of your loop.

To fix this, you simply need to declare `stringf` *within* your `for` loop:

```
for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++) { 
    var stringf;
    ...
}
```

Comment: same bro,only the last string was caught,anyway i think i need put the stringf on ajax and return it.

Comment: @DinaMalundras might be caused by this typo you have: `'+data</li>'`. That should be `'+data+'</li>'`.